# Click on checkbox and pass selected row to another datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having problems updating or replacing the rows found in my datagridview 1, when I select more than 2 rows from my datagridview 2

To display the information in datagriview 1 and datagridview 2 I am doing it with datasource as follows

Datagridview 1:

```
Dim dtsm As New DataTable
dtsm = negPern.Listar_Personalxempresa(VGlobales.Base, Me.cboempresa.SelectedValue)
Me.dgvListadoMarcador.DataSource = dtsm
Me.dgvListadoMarcador.Columns(0).ReadOnly = False
```

Datagridview 2:

```
    Dim dts2 As New DataTable
    dtsm = negPern.Listar_Personalxempresa(VGlobales.Base, Me.cboempresa.SelectedValue)
    Me.dgv1.DataSource = dtsm
    Me.dgv1.Columns(0).ReadOnly = False
```

this is reflected like this

[image]

The process of the update button is for the user to choose any row of the DGV 2 datagridview and if it exists in the Datagridview 1 or DGV 1 this will update it

So far I have managed to do it by selecting 1 by 1 with the following code

```
 Dim rownu As DataRow = dtsm.NewRow()
    Dim rowSelectedM As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)()


    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv2.Rows
            Dim cellSelecion As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = TryCast(row.Cells("ELEGIR"), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

            If Convert.ToBoolean(cellSelecion.Value) Then
                rowSelectedM.Add(row)
            End If
        Next


        For Each rown As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows
            If Convert.ToString(rown.Cells(3).Value).Equals(dgv2.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value) Then
                existeU = True
                fila = rown.Cells(3).RowIndex
            End If
        Next


        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rowSelectedM
            If existeU = True Then
                If MessageBox.Show("ESTE REGISTRO YA EXISTE EN LA BASE MARCADOR N° FILA :  " + " " + fila.ToString + " " + "DESEA ACTUALIZAR ?", "AUTONORT S.A.", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
                    'AQUI VA EL DTS


                    rownu("ACCION") = "U"
                    rownu("IDEMPRESA") = row.Cells(1).Value
                    rownu("IDCODIGOGENERAL") = row.Cells(2).Value
                    rownu("IDPLANILLA") = row.Cells(3).Value
                    rownu("FECHA_INICIOPLANILLA") = row.Cells(4).Value
                    rownu("A_MATERNO") = row.Cells(5).Value
                    rownu("A_PATERNO") = row.Cells(6).Value
                    rownu("NOMBRES") = row.Cells(7).Value
                    rownu("NRODOCUMENTO") = row.Cells(8).Value
                    rownu("LIQUIDADO") = row.Cells(9).Value
                    rownu("FECHA_INGRESO") = row.Cells(10).Value
                    rownu("FECHA_CESE") = row.Cells(11).Value
                    rownu("IDNACIONALIDAD") = row.Cells(12).Value
                    rownu("IDSUCURSAL") = row.Cells(13).Value
                    rownu("SUC") = row.Cells(14).Value



                    dtsm.Rows.RemoveAt(fila)
                    dtsm.Rows.InsertAt(rownu, fila)

                    dgv1.ClearSelection()


                    dgv1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dtsm.Rows.IndexOf(rownu)
                    dgv1.Focus()


                End If

            End If



        Next
```

When I select more than 2 rows I have the following error

Delete row number 2

The ideal is to replace the 2 selected rows of the datagridview and add the action U = update

[image]

Comment: First things first, why are you creating new `DataTable` objects and immediately discarding them? `Dim dtsm As New DataTable` is shorthand for `Dim dtsm As DataTable = New DataTable`. Why would you want to create a new `DataTable` and assign it to the variable if you're just going to assign some other `DataTable` to the variable on the next line? Don't create new objects when you declare a variable unless you need new objects. Just do this: `Dim dtsm = negPern.Listar_Personalxempresa(VGlobales.Base, Me.cboempresa.SelectedValue)`. The variable type will be inferred from the expression.

Comment: Next, why are you using `TryCast`? The whole point of `TryCast` is that it won't throw an exception if the cast fails but return `Nothing` instead. You don't test for `Nothing` because you know the cast will succeed, so don't use `TryCast`. Use `DirectCast` instead. That said, the cast is pointless anyway, because you never use any members of the type you cast as. All you use is `Value`, which is a member of the base class anyway.

Comment: As for the issue, I have no idea what that second loop is supposed to achieve but it looks problematic. You are setting two variables in that loop but those variables can only have one value each. You seem to be wanting them to have separate values for each row, but it's hard to tell because you haven't bothered explaining and there are no comments in the code.